# How to find an article title for specific post

Tags: database, nodes

So, I am new to drupal, and I am using a small pdo library to directly fetch from database list of articles, to display them on a page that is not running drupal. But, the articles are posted using drupal cms.

My problem is that, also I am able to fetch the article content, node id ... but I can't seem to find the title of article itself.

I looked in my table, and these are all the data I have.

```
mysql> describe field_data_body;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_type  | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bundle       | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted      | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id  | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| language     | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| body_value   | longtext         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| body_summary | longtext         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| body_format  | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Just as example, I am doing

```
$db = new DB(...);
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT *, entity_id as id, body_value as content from field_data_body where entity_id < 10  LIMIT 8"); 
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

foreach($result as $row){
  echo $row['title']; //error. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As with everything there are a few ways to do this. Here are a couple, if you know the node id.

Do a query on the node table:
`select title from node where nid = KNOWN_NODE_ID`

Use a Drupal function:
`$node = node_load(KNOWN_NODE_ID);`
`$nodeTitle = $node->title;`

Comment: thanks, but I believe all articles in drupal are stored in the `field_data_body` table, and I don't see a row called `title` or `node` or `nid`. If you mean to tell me how a select statement is done in mysql then, that is not what I meant. My question was specific to drupal and fetching article from a table.

Comment: Drupal uses more than one table for its content objects, or nodes. `field_data_body` (& `field_revision_body` for prior revisions) contains data for node body. It's the `node` table that contains the node title and other metadata related to nodes.

Comment: @ShawnConn so that means, if I posted one article on drupal (which i have done) i must look for the title, image, tags, contents on different tables?

Comment: Yes, if you want to get all the data you need in one set of results look at doing at doing an INNER JOIN query on  the `node`/`field_data_body` tables.

Comment: Is there any example or beginner-friendly way to do this?

Comment: If you are blindly capturing all titles from all articles you could still use the node table with an additional condition like `type = 'article';`